# Making thumbnail section width match thumbnail and not caption content in Twitter Bootstrap v3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, grid-layout

I am trying to display a row of thumbnails, each one with some caption content as per the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails).

My [attempt](http://pastebin.com/v4whcdpa) results in:[image]

It appears that the width of each thumbnail section is dictated by the caption content. However, I want the width to be just a little bigger than the thumbnail image like shown in the documentation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The width of your sections is dictated by the col-sm-6 col-md-4 classes. These will give 6 or 4 column width based on view-port. The caption width will always fill available space. give the section a fixed with of 242px

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to set the width of the image to something less than 100%. It can be your desired value like 80%.